# passing Queue out of class

Tags: python, queue

Really scratching my head here, trying to write a loopback test for a class I've created and getting some strange behaviour. The class that holds the queue seems to be fairly happy and can put data into it's queue. But the function that calls the class doesn't seem to think there is anything in the queue. Nothing else is trying to access this queue as it's an isolated unit test

Code looks something like this;

```
#mymqtt.py
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import Queue

class mqttcomms:
    def __init__(self, address, topiclist, monitorlist):
    #   ....
        self.msgqueue = Queue.Queue()
    # ....
    def on_message(self, client, userdata, msg):
    #   .... something that creates;
        newmsg = ['something','in','here']

        self.msgqueue.put(newmsg)
        print 'Message put in queue: ' + str(not(self.msgqueue.empty()))


# tests.py
import mymqtt
# ....
minortest('Basic Loopback')
##############  Basic Loopback ##############
testMQserver = 'localhost'
topiclist = ['test']
monitorlist = ['var1', 'var2']
mqttComms = mymqtt.mqttcomms(testMQserver, topiclist, monitorlist)

message = 'Hello'
mqttComms.publishmessage(topiclist[0], monitorlist[0], message)
message_ok = False

time.sleep(5)

print 'Message in Queue: ' + str(not(mqttComms.msgqueue.empty()))

while not mqttComms.msgqueue.empty():
    print 'Something in Queue'
    msg = mqttComms.msgqueue.get()
    print msg

    checks = 0
    if msg[0] == topiclist[0]:
        checks += 1
    if msg[1] == monitorlist[0]:
        checks += 1
    if msg[2] == message:
        checks += 1

    if checks == 3:
        message_ok = True
```

and what I get out is;

```
BASIC LOOPBACK 
MQTT: Connected to Server
MQTT: Published Hello to /test/var1
MQTT: Msg Received: test/var1 Hello
Message put in queue: True
Message in Queue: False
```

any ideas? If someone could explain why this is happening I'd be very grateful, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these queues actually the same object in the same process? It sounds like you may have made two completely unrelated queues.

Comment: thanks, you were right. I think the on_message callback spawns a new thread so I can't access the original 'mymqtt' class data to update the queue.I ended up getting around it using a dirty hack of global variables, if anyone could give me a better solution I'd be really keen to know how to 'do it properly'    :)